# How to center full width background image in header module?

Tags: css, joomla3.0

I am using joomla 3.4.5 with purity III template.

I placed a header module in "masthead" position.

I can't make my background image full width without any padding around.

Here you can see what I have:
http://prntscr.com/bwfno6

Here is the page where you can see the code:
http://spitzpomeranian.com/fr

This is the html code of my module:
`<

```
<div class="hearder_mobile" align="center"><br/><br/>
    <h1 style="color:#FFF">Vous recherchez un spitz nain poméranien?</h1>
    <p style="color: #CCC">Nous vendons des chiots poméranian de qualité avec pedigree</p>
        <div class="btn-actions" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <p><a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="#diagnostic">Voir chiots disponibles</a></p>
        </div>
</div>
```

`

And this is css of my div:
`.hearder_mobile{
        position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    height: 300px;}`

There are certainly other css parameters but I can't paste all the css code of all the tempalte here.

Is there any super CSS expert who can help me to fix that.

As you understood I need full width background image without any white surrounded the module.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, for security reasons, don't forget to update your site to the last version available.

Answer (score 1):

In your template.css file you have a set of rules giving padding to some elements around your image. The set of rules is somewhat complex, including media queries for different screen resolution, so you will have to look with the developer tools for what line / element to edit.

For example at line template.css:2851 you have

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) .page-masthead .row-feature {
 padding: 80px 0;
}
```

setting this line to `padding: 0;` will partially resolve your problem.

Setting the `background-size: cover;` for your background will also help to extend it to the full width and height of the element.

Answer (score 0):

The top padding comes from class `row-feature` so remove it or give it `padding-top: 0`. for the space from the right, to eliminate it you should give the background image `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

### Just Add two line in your css

```
.row-feature {
   padding-top: 0 !Important;
}
.custom div {
   background-size: cover;
}
```